# open any applications in mac like vlc, chrome, terminal from python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, automation

I am writing a script where if i say 'open vlc' then it should open the vlc application and if i say like 'open chrome' then it should open google chrome. For this i tried the following way but i get `permission denied issue` and also **the way i am doing is handling each application manually. Is there any other way i can open any mac applications?**

```
if 'open vlc' in query:
    subprocess.call(['/Applications/VLC.app'])
if 'open chrome' in query:
    subprocess.call(['/Applications/Google Chrome.app'])

# open system preferences, notes as well
```

Answer (score 2):

The Bash terminal that OS X uses actually has the `open` command, that should work with subprocess:

```
subprocess.call(["open", "-a", "ApplicationName"])
```

This uses, in my experience, `/Applications/` as a default location for the app. See also [the `man` page for the `open` command](https://ss64.com/osx/open.html).

In your case, I'd recommend making a dictionary or valid application names entered into your program, that can spit out the actual executable name of the program:

```
valid_programs = {
    "vlc": "VLC"
    "chrome": "Google Chrome"
}
```

To make a generalized "open" statement, you could use regex to identify the form of the command and capture the name they're trying to open, and then cross-reference that with `valid_programs`:

```
import re
...
app_name_query = re.match(r"open (.*)\b", query):
if app_name_query:
    try: 
        subprocess.call(["open", "-a", valid_programs[app_name_query.group(1)]])
    except KeyError:
        print(f"I didn't recognize the program {app_name_query.group(1)}!")
```

(you might need to alter the regex call a bit to match whatever format your queries work in - [see the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) for details on how to maybe do that)

Answer (score 1):

That's because `/Applications/Google Chrome.app` is a directory. You certainly do not have the permission to run a directory.

You can open `/Applications/<Application name>.app/Contents/MacOS/<Application name>` instead of `/Applications/<Application name>.app`:

```py
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.run('/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome')
CompletedProcess(args='/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome', returncode=0)
```

Full version:

```py
import subprocess


apps = {'vlc': 'VLC', 'chrome': 'Google Chrome'}

command = input()
if command.startswith('open '):
    try:
        app = apps[command[len('open '):]]
        subprocess.run('/Applications/' + app + '.app/Contents/MacOS/' + app)
    except KeyError:
        print('Unknown application:', command[len('open '):])
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print(app, 'is not installed.')
```

You can also match commands with [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) by using [module `re` in the Python standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

BTW, there's another module called [`cmd`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmd.html) in the Python standard library for interpreting line-oriented commands.